# Why Android losing its Location after long idle hours?

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation

```
try 
{  
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();   
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);  
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);   
    // Initialize the location fields  
    if (location != null)   
    {  
        onLocationChanged(location);  
    }   
}  
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

Hi Guys,

I am getting the Gp value from my above code using getLastKnownLocation().

The issue is the getLastKnownLocation() returning null rarely (or) sometimes (or) after long idle hours. No provider or network problems. All the required permissions are declared in manifest.

The solution to overcome this issue (i.e) to replace the null value with correct value could not be found.

When restarting the mobile, the getLastKnownLocation() is returning correct value. But that cannot be accepted as a solution every time.

There is no idea why the mobile is losing its location and when it is recovering its location.

I am developing an application that entirely depends on current location.

How to overcome this issue or any other alternate method is available to avoid this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Docs says that `null` can be returned, when the provider is offline. Maybe your code picks disabled provider? If you need precise position better start your own location listener using GPS (if it's available - if not, you can move user to settings screen to turn GPS on). You can also verify if `lastKnownLocation` is not too old (of course if it's not null) to use it as starting point.